# passport-local strategy working in postman but not in browser

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I've trying to set up authentication with email and password. Here's the partial code in signup.ejs:

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
    <% } %>

    <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
    <form action="/signup" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Signup</button>
    </form>
```

The form posts to `/signup` and this is my express route:

```
// process the signup form
app.post(
    '/signup',
    passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect: '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect: '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
    })
)
```

And this is the local passport strategy I'm using:

```
passport.use(
        'local-signup',
        new LocalStrategy(
            {
                // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
                usernameField: 'email',
                passwordField: 'password',
                passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
            },
            function(req, email, password, done) {
                // asynchronous
                // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
                process.nextTick(function() {
                    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
                    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
                    User.findOne({ 'local.email': email }, function(err, user) {
                        // if there are any errors, return the error
                        if (err) return done(err)

                        // check to see if theres already a user with that email
                        if (user) {
                            return done(
                                null,
                                false,
                                req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.')
                            )
                        } else {
                            // if there is no user with that email
                            // create the user
                            var newUser = new User()

                            // set the user's local credentials
                            newUser.local.email = email
                            newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password)

                            // save the user
                            newUser.save(function(err) {
                                if (err) throw err
                                return done(null, newUser)
                            })
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        )
    )
```

Here's a link to my [Github repo](https://github.com/edward-hong/auth) for the full code.

The problem I'm having is that when I'm making a post request with Postman with email and password in the request body, it turns out fine and I'm redirected to the profile route successfully. However when I try to login in by filling out the form on my page, I get redirected back to the '/signup' route. Can someone please help with this issue?

Comment: Generic tips: check and see if the verification handler for the strategy is getting called. Check and see if `email` and `password` contain the expected values. Check and see if any errors occur.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer. The reason is that the form wasn't passing the email and password values to req.body. I changed `app.use(bodyParser.json())` to `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` and it started working.